# List and generator - callers or functions responsibility

Tags: python

When calling a function that accepts a list, who is responsible (caller - a user, or called - the function) to ensure that it is a `list` and not a `generator`?

An example:

```
>>> def print_collection(coll):
...     for element in coll:
...         print element

>>> def print_collection_twice(coll):
...     print_collection(coll)
...     print_collection(coll)
```

With a list it will work without surprises:

```
>>> print_collection_twice( [x*2 for x in xrange(3)] )
0
2
4
0
2
4
```

And with a generator, obviously it is printed only once, which might lead to a nasty bug:

```
>>> print_collection_twice( (x*2 for x in xrange(3)) )
0
2
4
```

What is the *best practice* here? Should a function assume a list, and a user is responsable to provide the `list`, or should the function do always `real_list = list(input_list)` at the beginning so the user does not care?

**Edit**

I *know* how to check type of the element and `assert`, my question is rather high level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either approach is defensible.  It is the responsibility of the function to *document* what kinds of arguments it wants, and the responsibility of the caller to pass arguments consistent with the documentation.  If the function says it wants a list and you pass a generator, there are no guarantees it will work.

The real question is what the function should *say* it wants, and the answer is that it should say just what it needs, and no more.  So don't say you need a list if all you really need is an iterable.  In general, if your function needs to use features of lists that general iterables don't have (e.g., indexing), then it should just use those features, and an exception will naturally be raised if someone passes in an argument that doesn't support them.  If your function doesn't need those features, then it doesn't need a list.

Your example is somewhat unrealistic because all it does is print the argument.  In real life you would almost always need to do something besides just consume the iterable, and the nature of that "something you need to do" would clarify what sort of argument you should accept.  For your specific example, though, I would say yes, call `list` on it (inside `print_collection_twice`, not inside `print_collection`).  The reason is that `print_collection_twice` wants to use the data more than once, which is not possible for a generic iterable.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is certainly to *document* what you need. Document if the argument should be an iterable or a sequence. Python's philosophy is to use duck-typing so you should simply try to use the argument as if it was a sequence.

If you want to check whether the argument is a sequence, a simple way of doing that without creating a new list is using the `len` built-in function:

```
>>> len(iter([1,2,3]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'listiterator' has no len()
```

If you get the exception you can either call `list`, or `tuple` to obtain a sequence or let the exception through and let the user handle it. Which "policy" to choose depends and it's completely up to you.  Python programmers should read carefully the documentation and pass arguments that will work well, so you could state that you want an iterable as argument and always call `list` to obtain a sequence, or state that you want a sequence and raise an error if the object is an iterable. I don't see the point of stating the argument should be a sequence when you allow also iterables.

By the way, if you simply want to iterate more than once over an iterable you can use [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).

For example:

```
def print_twice(iterable):
    old, new = itertools.tee(iterable)
    for element in old:
        # do stuff
    for element in new:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: `itertools.tee` is a good idea for the general issue, but for this particular use it's not the best.  According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee): "In general, if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use `list()` instead of `tee()`."

Comment: @BrenBarn I just wanted to point out an alternative. I think the OP should profile the possible solutions and see which one works better for his situation.

Comment: "The best practice is certainly to document what you need." Disagree. Best practice is to fail on bad input

Comment: "Python programmers should read carefully the documentation". `s/Python/All/g`

Comment: @JakubM. Yes, fail on bad input and let the user try thousands of time to get the exact format your function accepts?

Comment: I am able to accept partial agreement here... document *and* fail fast

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion it depends on the application inside the function. The important thing is, that you *document* whether your function accepts only lists or iterators as well. An explicit `list()` call inside the function could cause a superfluos overhead for long lists, which is not necessary, if you only want to iterate over the list/generator once.

Comment: You can try `len(argument)` and see if it throws an error.
This does not have much overhead and should always work.